# Pegar DDD nos (11) com regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

preciso pegar o DDD que está entre os paretenses:

(11) 9.9999-9999

Tentei fazer uma regex mas não obtive sucesso. Usarei o PHP para pegar, mas precisava de uma regex pra isso. Alguém poderia me da uma mão.

Comment: Isso `^\((\d{2})\)` ajuda ? https://regex101.com/r/aYYEtd/2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a expressão `^\((\d{2})\)`

#### Explicando:

- `^` - Corresponde ao início de uma string sem consumir nenhum caractere.
- `\(` e `\)` - Escape é necessário para ser tratado como texto e não como um conjunto.
- `(\d{2})` - Captura e agrupo o DDD.

Veja em [PHP Live Regex](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oiy)

#### Código

```
$Telefone = '(11) 9.9999-9999';
preg_match("/^\((\d{2})\)/", $Telefone, $Saida);
print_r($Saida);
```

Saida

```
Array
(
    [0] => (11)
    [1] => 11
)
```

Veja funcionando em [eval.in](https://eval.in/1020960)

Answer (score 5):

A resposta do [@NoobSaibot](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/60376/noobsaibot) é muito boa, mas gostaria de deixar uma variação onde você consegue o mesmo resultado usando **[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-split.php)** com uma Expressão Regular diferente.

```
<?php
$string = "(11) 9.9999-9999";
$ddd = preg_split("/\(|\)/", $string);
echo $ddd[1]; // retorna 11
?>
```

Explicação da regex:

```
\( -> abre parênteses
|  -> "ou"
\) -> fecha parênteses
```

Isso irá quebrar a string em array pelos dois parênteses (abrindo e fechando), resultando em:

```
Array
(
   [0] => ""
   [1] => "11"
   [2] => " 9.9999-9999"
)
```

**[Teste no Ideone](https://ideone.com/gdq6sz)**

Comment: Eu não conhecia essa função do *PHP*.

Comment: show de ⚽️ rs...

Comment: Seria um explode usando regex.